# child of a canvas is layered under another canvas in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, z-index

i'm making a crossroad for a school project.
i have 4 lanes with a rectangle as a car that drives on them.
the problem is that car 1&2 drive under the crossroad and `Panel.ZIndex` doesn't seem to work.

XAML looks like this:

```
<grid>
  <canvas>                                //this is the 1st lane
    <rectangle x:Name= "blauweAuto" />   //this is the 1st car
  </canvas>
  <canvas>          //this is the 2nd lane
    <rectangle />   //this is the 2nd car
  </canvas>
  <canvas>          //this is the 3th lane
    <rectangle />   //this is the 3th car
  </canvas>
  <canvas>          //this is the 4th lane
    <rectangle />   //this is the 4th car
  </canvas>
</grid>
```

in the crossroad where al 4 canvasses overlap (yellow middle). the cars of the first drawn lanes (canvas 1 & 2) drive under the road. so i assume they are layered under the other canvasses. i tried Zindex but from what i read on the net that only works for children of the same objects. any idea's?

[image]

FYI i use one canvas per lane to move the car easier

```
private void BeweegBlauweAuto(double snelheid)
{
    blauweAuto.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(blauweAuto.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX + snelheid,0);
}

//DipatcherTimer triggers this event
  private void TimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      BeweegBlauweAuto(10);
  }
```

Comment: Putting the cars inside lane canvases is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the ZIndex in your `<canvas>` element instead of the `<rectangle>` element.
All the canvas elements are children of the `<grid>` element so their ZIndexes will be shared.

As per the comments below, just re-designing your XAML structure so the canvas and car elements are not coupled with each other will be a better approach as they can be moved as two separate entities without having to worry about where they lie on the ZIndex stack.

Comment: this does not work. if i give al 4 canvass the same ZIndex the problem stays. if i lower the ZIndex of the cavas that is drawn on top. the problem changes to the other 2 cars driving under the crosroad

Comment: @Korosevar I see what you are trying to do now, you may have structured the XAML incorrectly because only one canvas can be on top at the same time. You will need to take the car out of the canvas or they will be binded to the canvas's ZIndex

Comment: @Korosevar A workaround with your current XAML structure would be to set ALL the canvas ZIndex to 0. And then you use programmatically set the ZIndex to 1 for the canvas that the car is on (remember to reset it to 0 when its done driving). This has a limitation that only 1 car can be driving at the same time.

Comment: ok ty. that might actualy work. since i have to implement stoplights. and i can stil use 2 lanes that are next to each other.